# Is there a way to connect to Exchange Online using Logic Apps? Do I need to use a REST-api or EWS?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, azure-logic-apps

i'm quite new to Logic Apps. I got the task to make an auto reply function within Logic Apps that integrates with Exchange Online. Now I already performed this task using Outlook, but I have to be able to apply it to multiple mailboxes or even the entire company using Exchange. I'm about to get access to the Exchange Admin Center soon, but I don't really know how to start due to the fact that there is no simple way to make a connection to Exchange using Logic Apps. After some research, I think it's necessary for me to somehow make use of a REST API (I also read about the use of Exchange Web Services) to get the information I need, but my knowledge about this is quite small. I guess I'm gonna have to use a program like Postman to request information, so that I can start creating Custom Connectors to Exchange. If anybody has some understanding about this, feel free to reply and help me out! I will forever be gratefull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different approaches you could take to this if you (or probably they in your case) want your logic app to do all the work then you should use the Graph API rather then EWS (while its possible because its older API you'll loose marks on your assignment) have a look at http://martink.me/articles/using-microsoft-graph-in-logic-apps which covers the basics of what to do. To Get access to mailboxes tenant wide then you need to assigned Application Permission and get certificate (and store that in the KeyVault on Azure etc).

You can do this using Inbox Rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-post-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and the Exchange Server will do all the work when it comes to doing the Auto-response (and has loop detection logic already) and your logic app then just need to do the Creation and management of the Rules.

But I would suggest you clarify with the person who assigned you the task whether they want the logic app to do the response (eg using the Graph API) or if its okay for the Exchange Server to do this for then  (which should be more reliable).

You can also create Rules via the Exchange Admin Center and you could probably also through in Power Automate into the mix to do Autoresponse's so I'd clarify what they want so you don't waste time building something they don't want.